# Yii2 Rest API extra patterns with multiple controllers

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have 2 controllers in my API. Each has extra patterns defined. All of my actions work properly except the user login, which is defined in extra patterns.

```
<?
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'enableStrictParsing' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
        [
            'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
            'controller' => [ 'v1/item', 'v1/user'], 
            'tokens' => [
                '{id}' => '<id:\\w+>', //commenting out this token allows login to return
                '{type}'=>'<type:\\w+>'
            ],
            'extraPatterns' => [
                'POST {id}/image/{type}' => 'image', //from the item controller
                'GET login' => 'login' // from the USER controller
            ]
        ]

    ],
],
```

user/login errors as so. Note it's looking for the v1/user/view action

```
 {
    "name": "Not Found",
    "message": "Page not found.",
    "code": 0,
    "status": 404,
    "type": "yii\\web\\NotFoundHttpException",
    "previous": {
        "name": "Invalid Route",
        "message": "Unable to resolve the request: v1/user/view",
        "code": 0,
        "type": "yii\\base\\InvalidRouteException"
    }
}
```

If I comment out the ID token in the urlManager, the user/login action works, but my other routes fail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved by separating the rules into an item for each controller:

```
[
    'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
    'controller' => 'v1/config', //, 
    'tokens' => [
        '{id}' => '<id:\\w+>',
        '{type}'=>'<type:\\w+>'
    ],
    'extraPatterns' => [
        'POST {id}/image/{type}' => 'image',
    ]
],

[
    'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 
    'controller' => 'v1/user', 
    'extraPatterns' => [
        'GET login' => 'login'
    ],
]
```

Comment: Hi how can I add date token? I have also posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73578796/6854117). Can you pl check it?

Answer (score 0):

When you specify tokens

```
'{id}' => '<id:\\w+>',
```

you override default  yii\rest\UrlRule tokens

```
'{id}' => '<id:\\d[\\d,]*>',
```

and view route start translate into following

```
'GET,HEAD {id}' => 'view',
/user/<id:\\w+>
```

where id is a word so /user/login is translated into view action

Comment: Hi how can I add date token? I have also posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73578796/6854117). Can you pl check it?